# access an array from known address

Tags: c, arrays

I have a code that I passed a certain place in the memory. This place in the memory is pointing to an `array`

```
uint32_t *ps2 = NULL;
uint32_t src_address = 0x1ffffc3;
```

How can I read the value of the `array` from this address?
I tried to cast it as follows

```
*ps2 = (void *)src_address;
```

but it gives me an error: `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uint32_t`

Regards,

Comment: What type are the varables stored inside that array? Is this an array of 32-bit unsigned integers stored in native machine endianess?

Comment: Thanks friends, Basically I have the address that I need to access in the src_address and I need to convert it so I can access its content.

Comment: I tried also to deifne uint32_t ps2value = 0; uint32_t *ps2 = &ps2value; it also gives me the same error.

Comment: `Basically I have the address that I need to access in the src_address and I need to convert it so I can access its content` address is address. You can convert the type of the variable, not the address. You have an address `uint32_t src_address`. You can convert the type to `uint32_t *src_address_pnt = (uint32_t*)src_address`. If your compiler is really pedantic, try 
 `uint32_t *src_address_pnt = (uint32_t*)(void*)(uintptr_t)src_address`. Also please post _full_ exact error  message, include relevant compiler and compiler options.

Comment: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
          *ps2 =  (uint32_t *)src_address;     //
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: invalid conversion from ‘uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}’ [-fpermissive]
          *ps2 =  (uint32_t *)src_address;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Yes, right. So to hide the warning, cast to `uintptr_t` then to `void*` then to `uint32_t*`. `(uint32_t*)(void*)(uintptr_t)src_address`. Or maybe the best for warnings and the most unsafe -  `uint32_t *ps; static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t*) == sizeof(uint32_t), ""); memcpy(&ps, &src_address, sizeof(uint32_t));`

Answer (score 8):

You have *two* problems:

1. First of all, the pointer `ps2` is a null pointer, it doesn't point anywhere. That means you can't dereference it.
2. `src_address` is not a pointer, when it really should be.

All in all there's seems to be some mixup in your understanding of pointers and how they are used.

For it to work, first define `ps2` as *not* a pointer:

```
uint32_t ps2;
```

then define `src_address` *as* a pointer:

```
uint32_t *src_address = (uint32_t *) 0x1ffffc3;
```

and finally dereference `src_address` like a normal pointer:

```
ps2 = *src_address;
```

---

There is a possible third problem: The address of `src_address` is not aligned for an `uint32_t`. On some systems unaligned access is invalid and will lead to hardware exceptions.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working also error: invalid conversion from ‘uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘uint32_t {aka unsigned int}

Comment: @asd That looks like you forget to dereference the pointer on on the right-hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot guaranteely convert a pointer type to any integer type. `6.3.2.3(p5)` (emp. mine):

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type.  Except as
>   previously specified, the result  is  implementation-defined.  **If  the**
>   **result  cannot  be  represented  in  the  integer  type, the  behavior**
>   **is  undefined**.  The  result  need  not  be  in  the  range  of  values
>   of  any integer type.

The undefined behavior may well be the compile error you see.

There are dedicated types `intptr_t`, `uintptr_t`. They are described at `7.20.1.4`

> The  following  type  designates  a  signed  integer  type  with  the 
>   property  that  any  valid pointer  tovoidcan  be  converted  to  this
>   type,  then  converted  back  to  pointer  tovoid,and the result will
>   compare equal to the original pointer

If your implementation implements the types you should use them. If no there is no any other conforming portable way to convert integers to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give pointer p2 while (other than NULL).

But here you set this value not to pointer itself, but to memory it points to.

```
*ps2 = (void *)src_address;
```

And it points to....well nothing, it's NULL pointer (address 0 is not valid).

By using * you are accessing (or setting) value that pointer points to. So you need to remove * to change the pointer itself.

```
ps2 = (void *)src_address;
```

Or even better:

```
ps2 = (uint32_t*)src_address;
```

Then to read value from that address:

```
uint32_t value = *ps;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t *ps2 = NULL; // Assuming this is where you want your array to point.
uint32_t src_address = 0x1ffffc3; // source array
```

You can do :

```
ps2 = (uint32_t *)src_address; // Assuming 32 bit machine
```

Now to access every element of array, all you have to do is -

```
*ps2[0], *ps2[1]
```

`ps2[0]` will point to src_address + 0.
`ps2[1]` will point to src_address + 4(As pointer type is `uint32_t`)